# Got an ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '>' when I was trying to export information in task scheduler to a csv file

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I wanna export all information in Windows Task Scheduler using Python, so I wrote the code as follows:

```
Import subprocess

subprocess.call(r'schtasks.exe / query / FO CSV > D:\tasks.csv /V')
```

Then I got **ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '>'**

But when I input `schtasks.exe / query / FO CSV > D:\tasks.csv /V` in cmd, it works.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In `cmd` it works because it's `cmd` interpreting the `>`. You aren't calling `cmd` here though, you are calling `schtasks`!

You can solve it in one of the following ways:

- Use [`shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) so that Python spawns a shell (presumably `cmd`, but that's actually determined by the `COMSPEC` environment variable) and runs the command there
- Run `cmd` explicitly: `cmd.exe /c "schtasks.exe /query /FO CSV > D:\tasks.csv /V"`
- Instead of using `>`, [capture the output in Python](https://www.kite.com/python/examples/4870/subprocess-get-the-output-of-a-subprocess-after-execution) and then write it into a file.